# Jest, mock Mongoose model with lean()

Tags: mongoose, jestjs

I'm testing a function that has a async call to a mode that I want to mock:

```
const someFunction = async (id) => {
  const data = await SomeModel.findById(id).lean()
```

So, I want to mock `SomeModel` in order to keep the logic of the code.

`data` should be an object like: `{ _id: 'someId' }`

But how should I do the mock with the `lean()` method applying to `SomeModel.findById`?

I tried this:

```
SomeModel.findById.mockReturnValueOnce({ _id: 'someId' })
SomeModel.findById.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve({ _id: 'someId' }))
```

But it has no logic, because what I need to mock is that whole line including `lean()`
any hint?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with:

```
SomeModel.findById.mockImplementationOnce(() => ({
  lean: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ _id: 'someId' }),
}));
```